# SWIG wrapped C++ object created from python prematurely deleted

Tags: python, swig

I wrapped a C++ class and a C++ function in python with SWIG.

```
class Module { ... };
void register_module(Module *m);
```

Function register_module() puts the given module in a global list so that from then on the C++ code holds a pointer on the module, and uses it.

Now, the following python code, run from the embedded python interpreter, **crashes**:

```
>>> register_module(Module())
```

On the other hand, the following python code **doesn't crash**:

```
>>> m = Module()
>>> register_module(m)
```

Obviously, the reason is that in the first case the object is garbage collected by python while in the second case it is not.

What is the best way to prevent python from deleting the anonymous object created in the first case and used by the C++ code?

Is there a way, in the register_module() function, to get a hold on the associated python proxy object, and then to increase its reference count?

(I know this to be possible if the class in question can be cross-casted to a Swig::Director class, but that supposes that we have an instance of a Module subclass that was defined in python, which is not the case here).

Answer (score 1):

Solution.
**Step 1**: Add a member to the Module class, and two methods.

```
class Module {
public:
    PyObject *obj;
    void incref() { Py_INCREF(obj); }
    void decref() { Py_DECREF(obj); }
    ...
};
```

**Step 2**: Increase reference count in register_module().

```
void register_module(Module *m) {
    m->incref();
    ...
}
```

(not forget to decrease it somewhere)

**Step 3**: Hack the SWIG-generated wrappers to set the obj member to the PyObject wrapper whenever a Module object is constructed from Python.

In SWIG-generated file ModulePYTHON_wrap.cxx, locate:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_new_Module(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  ...
  Module *result = 0 ;
  ...
  if ( arg1 != Py_None ) {
    /* subclassed */
    result = (Module *)new SwigDirector_Module(arg1);
  } else {
    result = (Module *)new Module();
  }

  resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_Module, SWIG_POINTER_NEW |  0 );
  return resultobj;
  ...
}
```

Insert `result->obj =` before `resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_Module, SWIG_POINTER_NEW |  0 );`
We obtain:

```
  result->obj = resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_Module, SWIG_POINTER_NEW |  0 );
```

**Step 4**: Instruct SWIG to automatically implement the fix in the generated wrappers.

Add the following typemap declaration in the interface file.

```
%typemap(out) Module* {
   result->obj = $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_Module, SWIG_POINTER_NEW |  0 );
}
```

This effectively overrides the code that would be generated by default for wrapping a new Module object.

Comment: In case the class has a director, the hold should be on the director python object. The typemap code would then become: $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_Module, SWIG_POINTER_NEW |  0 ); Swig::Director *dr = dynamic_cast<Swig::Director*>(result); result->obj = dr ? dr->swig_get_self() : $result;